# Using join within same table in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

**In my table I have the following:**

[image: Database]

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a multi-lingual website, where my `change language` button goes through a check, to see if there is a page that is relative to the current one, in another language.

Let's say I enter `www.example.com/contact-us` whenever I change language, in this case, lets say Norwegian. I want to see if there is any correlating page in Norwegian. Which in this case is `www.example.com/kontakt-oss`

I'm trying to use the value `language ID` which is the language I want `(2)`, and the current page, which is `contact-us`. How can I make a select query that outputs `kontakt-oss` from these two values?

I've tried `LEFT JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
// CHECK IF PARALELL LANGUAGE PAGE
$sql2 = "SELECT page_name "
. "FROM pages "
. "WHERE page_relations IN (SELECT page_relations FROM pages WHERE page_name = :pagename) AND page_lang = :language";
$query2 = $db_connect->prepare($sql1);
if($query2->execute(array(':pagename' => $get_website_page,':language' => $echomenu['language_id']))){
    echo "/test";
    var_dump("GO!");
}
else{
    var_dump("ERROR");
}
```

I have checked the following values `get_website_page` outputs: contact-us

And `$echomenu['language_id']` output: 2.

However, query simple does not run and outputs ERROR.

Comment: Where is your column `language id` on the image? Can you show your table structure. I see no language ( eg Norwegian ) nor language ID on it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos See question update. You can see the process I have tried so far, and how I fetch the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl 
WHERE page_relations IN (SELECT page_relations FROM tbl WHERE page_name='contact-us')
AND page_lang=2
```

Comment: @GjertIngarGjersund pls provide meaningful feedback to those who try to help you! Your feedback is useless.

Comment: nevermind, it worked! :) Simply just a number mistake from my site :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your current page has page_lang as 1, then the MySQL query is

```
SELECT 
    p2.page_name
FROM
    tableName p1
        INNER JOIN
    tableName p2 ON p1.page_relations = p2.page_relations
        AND p1.page_lang <> p2.page_lang
        AND p1.page_relations == 4 //current page_relations
        AND p1.page_lang == 1;  // current page_lang
```

If your current page has page_lang as 2, then the MySQL query is

```
SELECT 
    p2.page_name
FROM
    tableName p1
        INNER JOIN
    tableName p2 ON p1.page_relations = p2.page_relations
        AND p1.page_lang <> p2.page_lang
        AND p1.page_relations == 4
        AND p1.page_lang == 2;
```

you can pass the **current page_relation** value orr the current **page_lang value** as arguments to your function

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be dynamic, and the page_relations has to be discovered inside the query. Not put manually. If I enter contact-us, and change language to Norwegian, the query should see that contact-us in language nr. 2 = Kontakt us. Because of the similarity in the relation code.